# The issue with padding

Tags: html, css

I'm just starting to learn HTML and CSS.
I have encountered a problem. I created a sidebar menu and set its height to 100% of the page, but when I apply padding to it, the bottom part of the menu shifts downward.
I hope for assistance from knowledgeable people, thank you.

```css
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  flex: content;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 144.04">
      "Here is an SVG image"
    </svg>
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li><a href="#">Портфолио</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Обо мне</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="socials-menu">
    <svg width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 65" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        "Here is an SVG image"
      </svg>
    <svg width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 65" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        "Here is an SVG image"
      </svg>
    <h2>@tupagon</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

[With padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFyuY.png)

[without padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwclV.png)

I would like the menu to have equal spacing both at the top and bottom, so that the content does not shift downward.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

Add the box-sizing property to the **.menu** class so fix the move the outside menu and see into the all menu in screen and fix the equal spacing both at the top and bottom

```
.menu {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Add the CSS in your style and see the fulfil your requirement.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.menu {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    flex: content;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 144.04">
        "Here is an SVG image"
    </svg>
    <ul class="menu-list">
        <li><a href="#">Портфолио</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Обо мне</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="socials-menu">
        <svg width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 65" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            "Here is an SVG image"
        </svg>
        <svg width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 65" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            "Here is an SVG image"
        </svg>
        <h2>@tupagon</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```